# MatLab-->csv: Export data to csv file using dlmwrite in Matlab

Tags: matlab, csv

I was looking for how to trying to save some data into a csv file using Matlab and I found something that was useful. I use the data and code:

**data**

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8];
names={'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e' 'f' 'g' 'h'};
```

**code**

```
save('Test','names','A');
nomFile='Test.csv';
fid=fopen(nomFile,'w');
fprintf(fid,'%s,',names{:});
 fprintf(fid,'\n');
dlmwrite('Test.csv',A,'-append');

fclose(fid);
```

**answer**

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

but it only saves the data, the way I want if I don't specify any folder. So it will be saved on the same folder where the script is located. But I want to save it in **another folder** and it only gives **the numbers** part.

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

Any one know how can I put something like

```
dlmwrite('C:\Data_Analysis\Test.csv',A,'-append');
```

?

I'd appreciate for your help.

Bruno

PS: sorry, I still don't know how to put colors in the code to make it more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you write the `names` to a file at the local folder and not the other folder.

```
fldr = fullfile('c:','Data_Analysis');
nomFile=fullfile( fldr, 'Test.csv' );
fid=fopen(nomFile,'w');
fprintf(fid,'%s,',names{:});
fprintf(fid,'\n');
dlmwrite(nomFile,A,'-append');
fclose(fid);
```